# How to calculate Internet checksum?

Tags: checksum

I have a question regarding how the Internet checksum is calculated. I couldn't find any good explanation from the book, so I ask it here.

Have a look at the following example.

The following two messages are sent: 10101001 and 00111001. The checksum is calculated with 1's complement. So far I understand. But how is the sum calculated? At first I thought it maybe is XOR, but it seems not to be the case.

```
              10101001
              00111001
              --------
   Sum        11100010
   Checksum:  00011101
```

And then when they calculate if the message arrived OK. And once again how is the sum calculated?

```
               10101001
               00111001
               00011101
               --------
   Sum         11111111
   Complement  00000000  means that the pattern is O.K.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It uses addition, hence the name "sum".  10101001 + 00111001 = 11100010.

For example:

```
+------------+-----+----+----+----+---+---+---+---+--------+
| bin value  | 128 | 64 | 32 | 16 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 1 | result |
+------------+-----+----+----+----+---+---+---+---+--------+
| value 1    |   1 |  0 |  1 |  0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |    169 |
| value 2    |   0 |  0 |  1 |  1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |     57 |
| sum/result |   1 |  1 |  1 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |    226 |
+------------+-----+----+----+----+---+---+---+---+--------+
```

Comment: How is a carry handled? Is the carry simply discarded?

Comment: @Ayos: depends on the size of number. In theory, 1+1 = 10 and the extra ones just keep moving to the left. On real hardware, usually there will be an overflow at 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, and the meaning of the new number depends on whether you're using signed integers and whether you're dealing with a 1s complement or 2s complement system

Answer (score 8):

If by internet checksum you mean TCP Checksum there's a good explanation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20021005084753/http://www.netfor2.com/checksum.html) and even some [code](https://web.archive.org/web/20021005084753/http://www.netfor2.com/tcpsum.htm).

When you're calculating the checksum remember that it's not just a function of the data but also of the "pseudo header" which puts the source IP, dest IP, protocol, and length of the TCP packet into the data to be checksummed. This ties the TCP meta data to some data in the IP header.

[TCP/IP Illustrated Vol 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469) is a good reference for this and explains it all in detail.

Answer (score 3):

The calculation of the internet checksum uses ones complement arithmetic. Consider the data being checksummed is a sequence of 8 bit integers. First you need to add them using ones complement arithmetic and take the ones complement of the result.

NOTE: When adding numbers ones complement arithmetic, a carryover from the MSB needs to be added to the result. Consider for eg., the addition of 3(0011) and 5(0101).

3'->1100
5'->1010
    0110 with a carry of 1
Thus we have, 0111(1's complement representation of -8).

The checksum is the 1's complement of the result obtained int he previous step. Hence we have 1000. If no carry exists, we just complement the result obtained in the summing stage.

Answer (score 3):

The UDP checksum is created on the sending side by summing all the 16-bit words in the segment, with any overflow being wrapped around and then the 1's complement is performed and the result is added to the checksum field inside the segment.
at the receiver side, all words inside the packet are added and the checksum is added upon them if the result is 1111 1111 1111 1111 then the segment is valid else the segment has an error.
exmaple:

```cpp
  0110 0110 0110 0000
  0101 0101 0101 0101
  1000 1111 0000 1100
--------------------
1 0100 1010 1100 0001 //there is an overflow so we wrap it up, means add it to the sum
the sum = 0100 1010 1100 0010
```

now let's take the 1's complement

```cpp
checksum = 1011 0101 0011 1101
```

at the receiver the sum is calculated and then added to the checksum

```cpp
  0100 1010 1100 0010
  1011 0101 0011 1101
----------------------
  1111 1111 1111 1111 //clearly this should be the answer, if it isn't then there is an error
```

references:Computer networking a top-down approach[Ross-kurose]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example with a real header of an IPv4 packet.

In the following example, I use [`bc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bc.1p.html), [`printf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) and [here strings](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-here-string.html) to calculate the header checksum and verify it. Consequently, it should be easy to reproduce the results on Linux by copy-pasting the commands.

These are the twenty bytes of our example packet header:

```
45 00 00 34 5F 7C 40 00 40 06 [00 00] C0 A8 B2 14 C6 FC CE 19
```

The sender hasn't calculated the checksum yet. The two bytes in square brackets is where the checksum will go. The checksum's value is initially set to zero.

We can mentally split up this header as a sequence of ten 16-bit values: 0x4500, 0x0034, 0x5F7C, etc.

Let's see how the sender of the packet calculates the header checksum:

1. Add all 16-bit values to get 0x42C87: `bc <<< 'obase=16;ibase=16;4500 + 0034 + 5F7C + 4000 + 4006 + 0000 + C0A8 + B214 + C6FC + CE19'`
2. The leading digit 4 is the carry count, we add this to the rest of the number to get 0x2C8B: `bc <<< 'obase=16;ibase=16;2C87 + 4'`
3. Invert¹ 0x2C8B to get the checksum: 0xD374

Finally, insert the checksum into the header:

```
45 00 00 34 5F 7C 40 00 40 06 [D3 74] C0 A8 B2 14 C6 FC CE 19
```

Now the header is ready to be sent.

The recipient of the IPv4 packet then creates the checksum of the received header in the same way:

1. Add all 16-bit values to get 0x4FFFB: `bc <<< 'obase=16;ibase=16;4500 + 0034 + 5F7C + 4000 + 4006 + D374 + C0A8 + B214 + C6FC + CE19'`
2. Again, there's a carry count so we add that to the rest to get 0xFFFF: `bc <<< 'obase=16;ibase=16;FFFB + 4'`
3. If the checksum is 0xFFFF, as in our case, the IPv4 header is intact.

See the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum) for more information.

---

¹<sub>Inverting the hexadecimal number means converting it to binary, flipping the bits, and converting it to hexadecimal again. You can do this [online](https://tomeko.net/online_tools/inv.php?lang=en) or with Bash: `hex_nr=0x2C8B; hex_len=$(( ${#hex_nr} - 2 )); inverted=$(printf '%X' "$(( ~ hex_nr ))"); trunc_inverted=${inverted: -hex_len}; echo $trunc_inverted`</sub>